# I'm trying to include enqueue.php in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-hook

Please help with this error on wordpress:

> Blockquote Warning: include(/app/public/wp-content/themes/Lawrence Mugeri/lncludes/front/enqueue): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /app/public/wp-content/themes/Lawrence Mugeri/functions.php on line 7 Warning: include(): Failed opening '/app/public/wp-content/themes/Lawrence Mugeri/lncludes/front/enqueue' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/www/wp-content/pear') in /app/public/wp-content/themes/Lawrence Mugeri/functions.php on line 7
>   Blockquote

```
<?php // This is functions.php file
// Set up
//Includes
include( get_template_directory() . '/lncludes/front/enqueue' );
// Action & Fillter Hooks
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'lm_enqueue' );


<?php // This is enqueue.php file
function lm_enqueue(){
}
```

Comment: did you try to write `'/lncludes/front/enqueue.php'` instead of `'/lncludes/front/enqueue'`

Comment: Thanks a lot, the problem was on those two mistakes and also blank spaces between enqueue.php and closing bracket.